Using Whatsbox with soketi instead of pusher
I have installed soketi and its running as when i visit subdomain or ip, it shows OK, now i have installed whatsbox - whatsapp business api code on my domain and when i provide app key secret key app id of soketi insted of pusher, it is not connecting to soketi on my server, it is still trying to connect with pusher. I am not a developer, I need help connecting whatsbox site to soketi on my server. can anyone help me with this? What files and what code i need to edit. Please help.
I Installed Whatsbox, Changed broadcasting.php and bootstrap.js but anything isn't working.
